# Android publisher API can't restore subsciption after cancel it

Tags: android, subscription, google-play-developer-api

When i successfully cancel a user's subscription with the help of [subscriptions link command](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel), there is no option for the user to renew it in Google Play - i.e. there is no 'Renew' button.
Is the any option cancel subscription from back-end and save opportunity for user restore it?

Comment: What happens when you cancel the subscription through an Android device? i.e. by going through the `Play Store > (Menu) > Subscriptions > ...`

Comment: In that case all fine. User can restore subscription in Google Play.